# How to authenticate with certificates using sudslibrary in robotframework?

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I'm testing soap messages using RobotFramework and sudslibrary. I need to authenticate session with a certificate. Is there a way to do this? I did not find a mentioning of this in the documentation or trough googling, but I guess somebody else has had to run in to same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own questions if somebody else stumbles unto this same problem.

No, there is no (simple) way for doing this. Sudslibrary is based on suds and that support only Soap 1.1. Soap 1.1 does not support authentication with certification.

If possible, publish version of the service you are testing that uses basicHttpBinding ( accessible with Soap 1.1) This way you will not need the certificates.

Comment: Can you click the check mark next to your answer to signify that you accept your own answer?